# SSIS: How to Load differently named flat files from a folder using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I'm very new to SSIS packages so please forgive me if this is a simple query.

I have `2 SSIS` packages that have been set up;

The first picks up a `csv file`, formats the data slightly (cuts off a prefix in one of the columns) and places it in another folder with an updated `filename and timestamp`.
The Second package imports the formatted file into a `SQL database table`.

The issue that I have is that the incoming file names for the first package may differ, the structure of the data will remain the same.

Is there a way to configure the `flatfile connection manager` to pickup any files in the `C:Incoming\ folder?`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop container, to get the files in a folder, and use expressions in flat file connection to get it.

For a detailed answer, you can refer to this article:

- [Loop through Flat Files in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/)